# Magento - The proper way to add/remove features from admin order page?

Tags: php, mysql, magento, e-commerce

I'm about to imigrate my current platform (osCommerce) to magento and on the current platform I have a lot of customizations on the order page where you see all the order statuses, billing address, what the customer purchased etc.

I wanna make sure that on Magento the customizations gonna be on external files so in case there is an upgrade the customizations will not be overwritten...

What is the prpoer way to achive that?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Generally in magento all the customization put in phtml file or xml file. I think you need to change all the designing structure of order. so make you sure that all the changes put in your theme phtml file and xml file.

This is best way to do your changes and you will not face gradation problem.